# ggplot: how to change colors of vertical lines according to group id (in polar plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe (output of dput(df2)):

```
structure(list(angles = c(-0.701916320805404, 2.33367948606366, 
0.364313791379516, -0.228918909875176, -2.77064550417737, 2.97776037032614, 
-3.03604124258522, 2.10507549390108, 2.07708771915781, -0.0646656487453258, 
-0.701916320805404, 2.33367948606366, 0.364313791379516, -0.228918909875176, 
-2.77064550417737, 2.97776037032614, -3.03604124258522, 2.10507549390108, 
2.07708771915781, -0.0646656487453258, -0.701916320805404, 2.33367948606366, 
0.364313791379516, -0.228918909875176, -2.77064550417737, 2.97776037032614, 
-3.03604124258522, 2.10507549390108, 2.07708771915781, -0.0646656487453258
), id = c(9L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
6L), method = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("kd-clips", "QT-Clust", "True"
), class = "factor"), truid = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("angles", "id", 
"method", "truid"), row.names = c(940L, 474L, 889L, 298L, 222L, 
932L, 87L, 695L, 261L, 832L, 1940L, 1474L, 1889L, 1298L, 1222L, 
1932L, 1087L, 1695L, 1261L, 1832L, 2940L, 2474L, 2889L, 2298L, 
2222L, 2932L, 2087L, 2695L, 2261L, 2832L), class = "data.frame")
```

I run the following code to make the plot that follows:

```
df2$y <- as.numeric(as.factor(df2$method))  + 3
df2$yend <- df2$y + 1

library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
cx <- ggplot(df2, aes(y = y, x = angles))
cx + geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(id))) + ylim(0,6)  + theme_light() + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = NULL, breaks = df2$angles)+coord_polar() + 
  theme(legend.position="none",  panel.border=element_blank(), axis.title =
        element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank())
```

I get the following figure:

[image]

Almost there, but what I would like to get are two more things:

1. The radial lines to be colored according to the last column (true.id) of the df2 (which is the same color as the points in the third concentric circle -- same as that for id == "True").
2. I would like a radial scale also, marked at intervals of 30 (like at angles of 0, 30, 60, 90, ... 330. 0). However, I do not want the scale at the left (of the y's).
3. The above has 30 points, three replicates of each method at each angle. However, the figures only appears to plot 9 replicates, i.e. 27 points in total. (It is possible that two angles -- the one with 2.077 and the one with 2.105) are very close, so that they are really perhaps both there, but I can not tell because then what are the two points that are close to each other?

I have tried all day but could not get either of these to work, so I was wondering if anyone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably what you wanted (I know, long time ago now...).  Some of what you were getting wrong I actually couldn't quite tell, but it's nearly always a mistake to try to use the coordinate gridlines to show data - use geom_line or geom_segment for the data, and leave the gridlines to show the coordinates.  This solves both your need to have the lines coloured, and makes it easier for the x gridlines (ie the radial ones) to have the labels you want (whether I understood you correctly on this, re degrees v. radians, I'm not sure).

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

# your "angle" looks to be in radians, not sure how you want these converted to degrees?
# but let's set where we want the axis marks to be
br <- seq(from = -pi, to = pi, length.out = 7)

ggplot(df2, aes(y = y, x = angles)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(id))) + 
  theme_light() + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = angles, colour = truid)) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_x_continuous(lim = c(-pi, pi), breaks = br, labels = 0:6 * 60)  +
  theme(legend.position="none",  
        panel.border=element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```